# How to create a queue using RxJS

Tags: rxjs, queue, observable, rxjs6

I'm trying to figure out how the queueScheduler works in rxjs (version 6.2.2).
I'm running an express server and what I want to do is accept multiple requests, but the function `processMetricRequest2` should only process one item at at time, but the code below...when I access `/test1` twice in a row, it will call `processMetricRequest2` even though it hasn't finished (the `webMetrics` function takes a few seconds).
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? thanks!

```
router.get('/test1', function(req, res, next) {
  let fn = partial(processMetricRequest2, req.query.input);
  queueScheduler.schedule(fn);
  res.render('index', { id: 1, current: {url: req.query.input}});
});
async function processMetricRequest2(url, arg) {
  console.log('--processing:', url);
  let result = await webMetrics(url);
  console.log('--FINISHED: ', url);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The `queueScheduler` is designed for scheduling synchronous tasks in composed observables in a breadth-first manner. It is not designed for scheduling asynchronous tasks.

Comment: I thought the `await/async` part would make it synchronous.

Comment: Nope, `await/async` is syntactic sugar over the top of promises. You cannot make something that's asynchronous synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a queue and serially process requests. That can be done using `Subject` and `concatMap` with process function. `queueScheduler` has totally different meaning...

```
const { Subject } = require('rxjs');
const { concatMap } = require('rxjs/operators');

const queue = new Subject();

router.get('/test1', function(req, res, next) {
  queue.next(req.query.input);
  res.render('index', { id: 1, current: {url: req.query.input}});
});

async function processMetricRequest2(url) {
  console.log('--processing:', url);
  let result = await webMetrics(url);
  console.log('--FINISHED: ', url);
  return result;
}

queue
  .pipe(concatMap(processMetricRequest2))
  .subscribe();
```

Also in case of an error the queue will stop! The subscription will terminate. So you should make sure you handle errors in `processMetricRequest2`